# how to change or update the specific value of the state immutably

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutability

I'm new to js and react js with redux i'm trying to update a value of the global state immutably This is my current state

```
const initialState = {
  questions: [
    {
      id: 1010,
      name: "Inside which HTML element do we put the JavaScript?",
      questionTypeId: 1,
      options: [
        {
          id: 10,
          name: "javascript",
          isAnswer: false,
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          id: 11,
          name: "scripting",
          isAnswer: false,
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          id: 12,
          name: "script",
          isAnswer: true,
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          id: 13,
          name: "js",
          isAnswer: false,
          isSelected: false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 1011,
      name: "Javascript is a langague used for ?",
      questionTypeId: 2,
      options: [
        {
          id: 14,
          name: "ConsoleApp",
          isAnswer: false,
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          id: 15,
          name: "ShellApp",
          isAnswer: false,
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          id: 16,
          name: "WebApp",
          isAnswer: true,
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          id: 17,
          name: "MobileApp",
          isAnswer: false,
          isSelected: false
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 1012,
      name: "What is the full form of SPA?",
      questionTypeId: 3,
      options: [
        {
          id: 18,
          name: "Secured and Progressive App",
          isAnswer: false,
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          id: 19,
          name: "Single Page Application",
          isAnswer: false,
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          id: 20,
          name: "SOLID Principles for Application",
          isAnswer: true,
          isSelected: false
        },
        {
          id: 21,
          name: "None of the above",
          isAnswer: false,
          isSelected: false
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  Currentquestion: []
};
```

i would like to change the **isSelected** value to true from the questions array of which index having **questionTypeId:1** followed by the options array of index:0
Below is the reducer i tried to change the state immutably **action.payload** value from the ui is 1 and **action.value's** value from the ui is 0

```
case SELECT_ANS: {
      const question = action.payload;
      const index = action.value;
      // const newstate = produce(state, draftsate => {
      //   draftsate.questions[question].options[index].isSelected = true;
      // });
      return {
        ...state,questions:[
          {
            ...state.questions[question],options:[{
              ...state.questions[question].options[index],isSelected:true
            }]
          }
        ]
          ]
        ]
      };
```

I try to put all the information as much as i can if anything missing or inappropriate i'm sorry about  ,Any help with explanation would be really appriciated ,Thanks in Advance

Comment: It looks like you forgot to add `...state.questions` to the new `state.questions` array? Try composing the new state step by step, starting from the innermost level and moving up. Also, wanted to fix the messy indentation and noticed the brackets don't match up.

Comment: @ChrisG ,I'm sorry i'm new to this could you please help me with the code ?

Comment: There's a typo in `...state,questions` - no comma, but dot.

Comment: @muka.gergely no, `questions` is a key here, not a reference

Comment: Here's one way of doing this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/xbrvuef7/

Comment: Ahh... didn't pay attention :)

Comment: Thanks much @ChrisG your code is working fine ,think i have always think about more than one way of using spred operator it bit confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I notices you split your action's data into `action.payload` and `action.value`, this is against [the flux principles](https://github.com/redux-utilities/flux-standard-action#actions). You must put your data object in `action.payload` and get it like `action.payload.questionTypeId` and `action.payload.index`.

Well, you can change your store like

```
case SELECT_ANS: {
  return {
    ...store,
    questions: store.questions.map((question) => {
      if (question.questionTypeId === action.payload.questionTypeId) {
        return {
          ...question,
          options: question.options.map((option, index) => {
            if (index === action.payload.index) {
              return {
                ...option,
                isSelected: true,
              };
            }

            return option;
          }),
        };
      }

      return question;
    }),
  };
};
```

If I didn’t answer your question well enough, you can get more information in [redux docs](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-more-actions) or ask me personally.

Good luck learning!

Comment: Thanks for putting it to my attention yes you are correct i would have to make it like dispatch({type:actiontype,payload{value:value,index:index}) ?

Comment: @Hashimaslam, yes, you can do. And you can use action creators https://redux.js.org/basics/actions#action-creators